# TinyMCE editor does not show buttons in bar

Tags: 7

I need a WYSIWYG editor so I installed drupal [**wysiwyg module**](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) in `sites/all/modules` folder. Further I downloaded [**TinyMCE**](http://www.tinymce.com/) and installed it in `sites/all/libraries/tinymce`.

The editor configuration is correctly displayed in `admin/settings/wysiwyg/profile/2/edit`. My interface language is German and TinyMCE has this language pack installed.

When I go to edit some text in the backend the editor itself is initialized but no buttons are displayed.

Any ideas why there are no buttons and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable some button /admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/yourprofile/edit ?

If yes, this can be caused by a javascript error. Do you see one in Firebug ?

Comment: yes I enabled some buttons and there are no errors in firebug...

Comment: Well, seems like a tough one. Did you try to set the language to English (default) in TinyMCE options ?

Comment: I notices that drupal includes jquery 1.2.6, maybe this version is too old for tinymce?

Comment: as a fruther notice, I tried other editors too, none of them showed the buttons

Comment: Setting language to english did the trick, thank you

Comment: Great ! I had the same kind of trouble with the french package. I think there is a trick involving wysiwyg hooks to modify TinyMCE's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this clearer since others may not read the comments...

Try to set the language to English and make sure that each filter configuration is set to English (in my case one was French and the other English)

Answer (score 0):

**Installation:**
**Step 1:** In Drupal 7, Download Tinymce (I've used TinyMCE 3.5.11 jQuery package) from [here](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) and save as like the actual library can be found at:

> \sites\all\libraries\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce\jquery.tinymce.js

**Step 2:** Then reload the page and go to this location:

> /admin/config/content/wysiwyg

**Step 3:** Now choose tinymce from 'Editor' column for your appropriate 'Text Format' and click on the 'Save' button.

**Step 4:** Click on the 'Edit' button of tinymce enabled 'Text Format'.

**Step 5:** Make sure 'Language' is English in 'Basic Setup' tab.

**Step 6:** **By default all button and plugins are disabled**. So enable your required button  or plugins from 'Buttons and plugins' tab,**strong text** otherwise you'll not see any button in 'rich text' input mode.
[image]
*N.B.: Step 6 is the main answer of the question.*